# Install/Preinstall plugins in Intellij programmatically

Tags: snap, plugins, intellij

I would like to install some intellij plugins programmatically, after intellij is installed with snap, or prepackage an installation that would include those plugins as well.

I have tried to download the zip from plugins.jetbrains.com and then manually copy it under the plugins folder, but I cannot seem to be able to do this as the dir is "read-only"

```
root@HP-Pavilion:~# cp -r /home/jim/Desktop/NodeJS /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/plugins/ 
cp: cannot create directory '/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/plugins/NodeJS': Read-only file system
```

Is this doable?

**EDIT:** 
Found this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206109249-How-to-create-a-custom-idea-distribution-

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` at a root prompt?

Comment: Snaps are indeed read-only. File a bug with the [snap author](https://www.jetbrains.com/) about the need to link to a writable plug-in directory.  This may be non-trivial, as it will will require some thought about the AppArmor profile.

Comment: @user535733 because of a fast copy-paste of a previous run outside root ;)